# How to save an array as a text file on external server - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I thought that this would be a simple issue but I spent some time searching how to save an array object as a text file on my computer.
I have a js file with several functions and this file is called in html for the execution.
My project consists of clicking on the panoramic images and calculating their coordinates. When I obtain arrays of coordinates I want to save it in one text file which needs to be located on my external server (where the output files are). Then, there will be a lot of text files on this server, each with the arrays obtained from each user. Everything works fine except saving an output as a txt file. Lots of solutions suggest using Node module and filesaver or file-system modules within it but when I install node in the root folder where my project is, I don't know what to do next because nothing work. Here is the concept of what I want to do:

```js
function Calculate_Coordinates(){
// Here I obtain two arrays, X and Y coordinates when the user press any keyboard button.
// I'm not gonna write the code since it worked but only the output:
X = [1356, 1356, 1356, 1721, 1721];
Y = [130, 130, 130, 365, 417];
}

// Then I need to save these arrays of X and Y as a txt file after the user pressed a keyboard key for the 5th time.
let i = 0;
onkeydown = function(e){  
 i++;
 
 Save_Arrays_As_Text_Files(); // Here is the problem. How to do it 
 }
```

Comment: "$ seems to be wrong." — Yes. Take it out. Then use `fs` somehow.

Comment: The presence of `index.html` and files mentioning a mouse imply you are writing code that you intend to run in a browser and not in node though.